From which size is passing by const ref faster than copy?
I have read Is passing a char or short by reference or pointer slower than passing by value? and the first answer mentions the following:

no matter what you do compiler is free to change anything as long as it is not changing the observable behaviour of program. So it might be unimportant from this perspective since compiler can interchange (in both ways) pass by const T& and pass by T as long as it knows it makes no difference from semantic perspective

So, for implementations within the same compilation unit, it appers to not make any difference between const T& and T for trivial types.
But does this holds when the declaration is not in the same compilation unit from the implementation?
Also, can processors load more than one word with a ptr dereference?
I would like to know the threshold of when a copy is faster than a ptr de-reference. I tried messing on the compiler explorer but apparently there are some things happening that I don't know.
I know that this can be highly different based on the architecture and the instructions supported, by I would also like to know how to even test this.

"I would also like to know how to even test this...." Are you asking what happens in a particular architecture or just that how to test this for yourself. The answer to the latter is very different than the answer to the former.

There also seem to be multiple questions in the post.

If sizeof(param) <= sizeof(&param), then passing by value will probably be fine unless there's a custom copy constructor.  In general, pass plain old value types like char, float, double, long, int, bool, etc... by value.  Pass objects by const reference whenever possible to get the best compiler optimizations. Otherwise, fallback to passing by reference or pointer as needed.  If you stick to that basic set of rules, you'll have 99% of the cases covered.  There's exceptions, but it usually just doesn't matter until you profile your code to figure out where the bottlenecks are.

My rule of thumb:  if the parameter doesn't fit into a register, then pass it by const reference.

Regarding your title, modern processors and optimizations are far too complicated to make such blanket statements. The other questions should not be asked in the same post.

This has all sorts of annoying complications such as there being some thing bigger than a pointer that are trivial to pass by value in some circumstances (for example some structs can be passed in two registers such as this, and I'm not even talking about SIMD types yet but there's that too)

nice example @user555045

The caveats that don't allow for definitive answer are:

It greatly depends on ABI / calling convention. Like, how a structure/class is passed. Sometimes structure/class can be passed in one register, or in few register, and sometimes there is always a pointer, even for by value cases
Usually you'd assume that register size is pointer size, but there are vector types like x86 __m256i that are passed via registers (under certain calling convention on MSVC), they should be passed by value to serve their purpose.
It also depends on usage. Like if the parameter is unused, and you have it as a reference, better pass it by reference. Or if a two-register struct is passed alone, it is better by value via registers, but if only one register is left, reference may be better

Normally, anything pointer or less sized is better by value, and with greater size it is usually better by reference (but note the example of four member struct Caio Vinícius answer).

I know that this can be highly different based on the architecture and the instructions supported, by I would also like to know how to even test this.

Study the resulting codegen and profile it.

When the data is too large to fit in a CPU register, passing by reference is faster because it doesn't copy the value, and either way it can only be referenced by its address or its copies address (though, when passing by value, the compiler hides that).
It takes a ridiculous amount of processing power to copy it compared to simply reading it in such a case, because it has to copy in more than one instruction. By passing the address, it only has to copy that one address into a register.
Aside from that, it requires knowledge about how the registers and stack are being used (which C doesn't provide unless you want to use inline assembly or compile to assembly until it gives the best output), so most will simply have to trust that the compiler was well made.
If you wanted to know about a specific compiler, someone else could probably give you a more specific answer.

I think OP is already aware of this, given the details in their post.

So, from looking at the answers:
For types <= a word, copy is clearly faster. For sizes larger than a few bytes, such as, idk, 256 bytes, const reference is faster. The issue is the limbo with the sizes between that, such as:
struct {
uint64_t A;
uint64_t B;
uint64_t C;
uint64_t D;
}

this can not fit in a single register, but passing by value is probably faster if your function requires to read all members.
This would allow to copy each one to a single register before calling, and have the registers ready to be used in the function, instead of requiring to load the registers from the pointer.
But this depends if the function requires more parameters, which can cause the compiler to push the parameters into the stack instead, or if the struct is aligned, etc.
This is really hard to get a definitive answer, as alignment and compiler optimizations are not trivial.
I think, as pointed out, the best approach is to copy types that are less or equal than a word size, and use const reference otherwise.
As pointed by @selbie, profiling the code is the best approach to check if this is an issue and address that.

As a rule of thumb, pass primitive types by value, structs and classes and unions by reference.
